# Configure Azure monitor for application logs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-monitoring

Let us consider a hypothetical scenario where I have two VMs, each runnning a separate application e.g one running an internal dashboard (called Internal) and another running the main server (called External) for my application.

Both the applications have their log files in /var/log/application.log file in their respective machines. I want to be able to setup Azure Monitor such that I can search the logs of Internal and External machines/applications separately.

I found that there is no way to associate a VM to a filter in Azure Monitor `(LogAnalytics --> Advanced --> Data --> Custom Logs --> Add)`. It only takes a sample log file, path of the log file and adds it to the Custom Filters in the `Log` section of Log Analytics / VM.

In my opinion this will combine the logs found in both machines into a single stream and show them to me. OR I will have to name the log files `internal-application.log` and `external-application.log` and then add those in two separate filters and use that as a differentiating criteria.

I have tried looking into the documents and searching on the internet. All answers seem to be concerned with metrics logs of the VMs and not application logs.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK in your case, you need not name the log files say as 'internal-application.log' and 'external-application.log' because even if the log file path is same 
(say '/var/log/application.log') across multiple machines then the logs found are combined and showed into a single stream for particular log type named (say xxxxxxx_CL 
i.e., it may be any name which ever you have given while uploading the custom log) provided the logs will have a column named "Computer". So you may query the logs based on computer as well.

Example queries:

```
xxxxxxx_CL | where Computer == "VM1NAME"

xxxxxxx_CL | where Computer == "VM2NAME"
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hey Krishna, thanks for the answer. However I didn't understand this part ` it may be any name which ever you have given while uploading the custom log) provided the logs will have a column named "Computer".` Is this column present by default? or is there a way i can add it? I don't see any setting to associate the `xxxxxxx_CL` log stream to a VM (which if I remember correctly was present in the older OMS dashboard).

Comment: Tried and it worked. Is this the only way of doing it? Also if I go to a VM and click on Logs, will I automatically see the logs for that VM only? Because this seems like a solution where I need to create separate queries for each such application. We have a lot of applications hence the question.

Comment: Question1: Is this column (named "Computer") present by default? -> My answer: Yes.

Question2: Is this the only way of doing it? -> My answer: AFAIK this is the best and preferred way of doing it. There may be other custom ways by leveraging Azure Automation DSC, Azure Automation Runbooks, Logic Apps, Function Apps, etc.

Question3: If I go to a VM and click on Logs, will I automatically see the logs for that VM only? -> My answer: Yes. Provided that VM needs to be connected to the Log Analytics workspace where you have configured custom log setup.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ KrishnaG-MSFT Thanks a lot for all the answers.